# How do I pass the cardCode value to createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest for hosted CIM popup form

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

So I am using the Hosted CIM at Authorize.net to store customer information, they do not store the CCV cardCode.

How do I get the cardCode (entered via the CIM hosted popup form) so that I can process the createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest?

I have not required the CCV code, but transactions fail with the banks that require the code.

I am using the hosted CIM, I query the Customer ID and get the payment profile info using the below code:

```
$xml->createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest(array(
        'transaction' => array(
        'profileTransAuthCapture' => array(
            'amount' => $amount_,
            'customerProfileId' => $profile_id,
            'customerPaymentProfileId' => $paymentProfileID,
            'customerShippingAddressId' => $customerShippingAddressId,
            'order' => array(
            'invoiceNumber' => $invNo,
            'description' => 'Subscription'/*,
            'purchaseOrderNumber' => 'PO1'*/
            ),
            'taxExempt' => 'false',
            'recurringBilling' => 'false',
            'cardCode' => '000'
        )
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by removing the cardCode field:

'cardCode' => '000'

It was passing the incorrect value: '000' causing the transaction to fail with cardCode mismatch error.